# Run chrome with GUI on linux machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, redhat-enterprise-linux, remote

I would like to install and run chrome on linux machine. In addition, I would like to connect to the chrome instance remotely using my PC/Mac and control the browser with the GUI.

Is this possible?

So far, I have installed and launched Chrome on both Ubuntu and RHEL 7 linux machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp) extension.